# Can a message reach the client before an older message?

Tags: networking, websocket, socket.io

I'm curious if packet2 can reach the client before packet1 does due to network delays.

```
server.socket.emit('packet1', []);
user.socket.emit('packet2');
```

I'm using socket.io on a node.js server. I googled it a bit and couldn't find anything. (I am not good at finding something on Google)

Comment: What's exactly case you got?

Comment: It is entirely possible to have out-of-order packet delivery. TCP handles that situation for you, but UDP does not.

Answer (score 2):

socket.io runs over TCP which guarantees that packets are delivered in the order they are sent on the same connection.

So, if packetA is sent before packetB on the same socket.io connection, then packetA will always be delivered to the end client before packetB.

Your code example shows one packet being sent to `server.socket` and the other being sent to `user.socket`.  If those are different socket.io connections, then there is no guarantee at all about which will be delivered first.